# PHP Multiple Dropdown

Tags: php

This is my html partial code

```
<select name="number[]" style="width: 350px;" multiple="multiple" size="2">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>
</select>
```

PHP code

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$number= $_POST["number"];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' AND ");
```

What should i add after AND for the number so that query will work? I tried foreach but it didnt exactly work in query.

Comment: WTF: like downvoting good answers first time

Comment: It wasn't good answers. They would leave his website wide open security wise.

Comment: @phidah: you don't even if the user have `magic_quotes` enabled or anything + if every answer should point out security problems most of the question wouldn't be answerable ... I am ok with you downvoting obviously bad answer, after going on only war and even downvoting things approved by the poster is kind of a different matter.

Comment: @phildah: my last comment on this question, so you basically overlook other user answer and provide a buggy code snippet .... so don't know what to add more.

Comment: You're really the one starting a flame war. No need for that tbh. I downvoted two bad answers, and removed the one now that the answer has been corrected. Please grow up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$number= $_POST["number"];

if(!is_array($number)){
  // some error message or what.
}

$squery = '';
$a = array();
foreach($number as $n){
  // do some validation for $n
  // $number should be an array, so don't validate it.
  $a[] = "`number` = '$n'";
}
$squery = implode(' OR ',$a);
unset($a);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `name` LIKE '%$name%' AND (".$squery.")";
$res = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: @UFOman: can you upvote at least the good valided by the user answer won't have a -1, tks to @phildah

Comment: Still doesn't contain any output escaping, so my -1 stays.

Answer (score 1):

something like this I suppose

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' AND number IN (" . implode(',', $_POST['number']) . ')');
```

the [implode](http://us.php.net/implode) documentation

also please not you should be careful about escaping the data coming from users or your website is going to be [SQL injection vulnerable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @phidah: are you trying to be kind of ayatollah or ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$number= $_POST["number"][i];
```

put this in your loop

Answer (score -2):

My approach would be something like this:

```
<?php
if(is_array($_POST['number']))
{
   $numbers = implode("','", array_walk($_POST['number'],' mysql_real_escape_string')));
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($name%) . "' AND number IN ('" . $numbers . "')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: @phidah: for the record your first answer used `addslashes` which is not a proper escapement

Comment: RageZ if you could drop the hetz Stackoverflow would be a better place. At least I used _any_ escaping initially :)

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: I agree. Tried to clean it up a bit.